# Can't create a view with the Naviator

Tags: vaadin

I would really appreciate your help. I am not sure if my problems are being caused a fundamental misunderstanding of how the Navigator works or because of a small, stupid mistake. There are so few tutorials which explain how the Navigator works and they all show a different way to handle it.

I'm trying [this](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+bookmarkable+application+with+back+button+support) tutorial but I can only get my application to run if I make the class declaration: 
`public class CountView extends VerticalLayout implements View {` but that doesn't give me access to `setcontent()`. If I try `public class CountView extends Panel implements View {` then my program runs but I can't get access to `setcontent()`

Thanks again. I've really been battling for ages with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to call setContent in a view. The navigator takes care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But then how do I add the components I declare to the interface?

Comment: Your view class extends Vertical Layout. All you need to do is use addComponent method either in the constructor or the enter method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. Good luck.